# Custom iterator for a linked list class

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

I have made a `LinkedList` class. This is a singly-linked-list and I want to make a `forward_iterator` for this class without using Boost. I have made the code and I want to know whether I have implemented it correctly. The source I referred to make this code is [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/).

```
template <class T>
struct node
{
    T data;
    node *next;
};

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
    private :
    node<T> *start;
    unsigned int numElements;
    // Assume all functions are implemented
};
```

Iterator Code :

```
class iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,node<T>*>
{
    node<T>* itr;

    public :

    iterator (node<T>* temp) : itr(temp) {}
    iterator (const iterator& myitr) : itr(myitr.itr) {}
    iterator& operator++ 
    {
        itr = itr->next;
        return *this;

    }
    bool operator== (const iterator& rhs) 
    {
        return itr == rhs.itr;

    }
    bool operator!= (const iterator& rhs) 
    {
        return itr != rhs.itr;

    }
    T& operator*()
    {
        return itr->data;
    }

};
```

Is the above implementation correct? If not, then what changes should I make?  Also, does anything else need to be implemented?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Your iterator is missing a few important details:

- You should provide the pre- and post-increment operators (`++it` and `it++`). Currently, you only have the pre-increment version.
- It might also be good to provide the `->` operator, since some people prefer the `it->something` syntax over the `(*it).something` one.
- The comparison and dereference operators should be `const`. Remember [Const Correctness](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html).
- The copy constructor is just performing a memberwise copy of the underlying data, so you don't need to provide one and can let the compiler default it.
- The Standard Library containers always provide two flavors of iterators, the `iterator` type, pointing to mutable data, and the `const_iterator` type, pointing to immutable data. It is easy to adapt your class to support both by providing a conversion operator and inheriting from `std::iterator` (see the following example).
- Decide which course of action should be taken when incrementing and dereferencing an invalid iterator. E.g.: `list.end()++;`. Should it trigger an assertion? Throw an exception? Do nothing as it is now? I would at least assert to help the debugging process. You might find exceptions more appropriate in your context.

#### The above points applied to your code:

```
#include <cassert>      // assert
#include <cstddef>      // ptrdiff_t
#include <iterator>     // iterator
#include <type_traits>  // remove_cv
#include <utility>      // swap

template
<
    class Type,
    class UnqualifiedType = std::remove_cv_t<Type>
>
class ForwardIterator 
    : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,
                           UnqualifiedType,
                           std::ptrdiff_t,
                           Type*,
                           Type&>
{
    node<UnqualifiedType>* itr;

    explicit ForwardIterator(node<UnqualifiedType>* nd) 
        : itr(nd) 
    { 
    }

public:

    ForwardIterator()   // Default construct gives end.
        : itr(nullptr) 
    { 
    }

    void swap(ForwardIterator& other) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap(itr, other.iter);
    }

    ForwardIterator& operator++ () // Pre-increment
    {
        assert(itr != nullptr && "Out-of-bounds iterator increment!");
        itr = itr->next;
        return *this;
    }

    ForwardIterator operator++ (int) // Post-increment
    {
        assert(itr != nullptr && "Out-of-bounds iterator increment!");
        ForwardIterator tmp(*this);
        itr = itr->next;
        return tmp; 
    }

    // two-way comparison: v.begin() == v.cbegin() and vice versa
    template<class OtherType>
    bool operator == (const ForwardIterator<OtherType>& rhs) const
    {
        return itr == rhs.itr;
    }
    
    template<class OtherType>
    bool operator != (const ForwardIterator<OtherType>& rhs) const
    {
        return itr != rhs.itr;
    }

    Type& operator* () const
    {
        assert(itr != nullptr && "Invalid iterator dereference!");
        return itr->data;
    }

    Type& operator-> () const
    {
        assert(itr != nullptr && "Invalid iterator dereference!");
        return itr->data;
    }

    // One way conversion: iterator -> const_iterator
    operator ForwardIterator<const Type>() const
    {
        return ForwardIterator<const Type>(itr);
    }
};

// `iterator` and `const_iterator` used by your class:
typedef ForwardIterator<T> iterator;
typedef ForwardIterator<const T> const_iterator;
```

Note: In the example, I've assumed that the end of your list or an invalid iterator are marked by a null pointer. You'll need to change that if you are using some other method, such as a dummy sentry node.

Comment: This is a bit confusing, isn't that `std::iterator` is deprecated in `C++17`? If so, than how this should be updated to workaround the future deprecation state?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, `std::iterator` is being deprecated, but it was a class that just contained typedefs for its template arguments, so it suffices to simply write each of the required typedefs as members of the iterator class instead.

Answer (score 14):

The requirements for a forward iterator are:

- [Forward Iterator](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/stl/ForwardIterator.html)

It is a refinement of:

- [Input Iterator](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/stl/InputIterator.html)
- [Output Iterator](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/stl/OutputIterator.html)
- [Trivial Iterator](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/stl/trivial.html)
- [Equity Comparable](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/stl/EqualityComparable.html)
- [Default Constructable](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/stl/DefaultConstructible.html)
- [Assignable](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/stl/Assignable.html)

If you read through all those specs you must define these:

- Preincrement
- Postincrement
- Dereference (Read/Write)
- Default Constructable
- Copy Constructable
- Assignment operator
- swap
- Postincrement and de-reference
- Postincrement and assignment
- Member accesses (-> when de-referencing returns an object with members).
- Comparable with == and !=

You must also define these types:

- Value type
- Distance type

You are missing:

- The types.
- Postincrement
- Default Constructable (This gives you the equivalent of end of any list).
- swap
- Member accesses (-> when de-referencing returns an object with members).

Comment: sgi links are no longer available.

Comment: SGI now hosted here: http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/stl/

Comment: But you can look up all these terms here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp (or by reading the standard).