# Static array wrapper with iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel

This is just like `std::array<T, N>`. I wrote this for practice. The class is in a different namespace, so the name `array` stands!!

There is only one bug (that I'm aware of) and that's the `base()` function for the reverse iterators. Works fine with `const_reverse_iterator`, but if I do the following:

```
auto i = arr.rbegin();  //i is array<T, N>::reverse_iterator
auto j = i.base();   //j is std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, T>
```

So I could use a little help with that!

Sorry about the lack of horizontal space! It looks too good in an IDE with more space!

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e39f5760f67fa533

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template<class ArrType, std::size_t Size>
class array
{
public:     //TYPE ALIASES
    using value_type      = ArrType;
    using size_type       = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using reference       = ArrType&;
    using const_reference = const ArrType&;
    using pointer         = ArrType*;
    using const_pointer   = const ArrType*;

private:
    class array_iterator : public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, value_type>
    {
    protected:
        pointer _pos;

    public:
        explicit constexpr array_iterator(pointer pos)
            : _pos(pos)
        {}

        constexpr array_iterator() = default;
        constexpr array_iterator(const array_iterator&) = default;
        constexpr array_iterator(array_iterator&&)      = default;

        //ASSIGNMENT OPERATORS
        array_iterator &operator=(const array_iterator&) = default;
        array_iterator &operator=(array_iterator&&)      = default;

        //COMPARISON OPERATORS
        constexpr bool operator==(const array_iterator& rhs) const { return _pos == rhs._pos; }
        constexpr bool operator!=(const array_iterator& rhs) const { return _pos != rhs._pos; }
        constexpr bool operator>(const array_iterator& rhs)  const { return _pos > rhs._pos; }
        constexpr bool operator<(const array_iterator& rhs)  const { return _pos < rhs._pos; }
        constexpr bool operator>=(const array_iterator& rhs) const { return _pos >= rhs._pos; }
        constexpr bool operator<=(const array_iterator& rhs) const { return _pos <= rhs._pos; }
    };

public:
    class const_iterator : public array_iterator
    {
    public:
        using array_iterator::array_iterator;

        //INCREMENT/DECREMENT OPERATORS
        const_iterator& operator++() { ++array_iterator::_pos; return *this; }
        const_iterator& operator--() { --array_iterator::_pos; return *this; }
        const_iterator  operator++(int) { const_iterator temp(*this); operator++(); return temp; }
        const_iterator  operator--(int) { const_iterator temp(*this); operator--(); return temp; }

        //ARITHMETIC OPERATORS
        const_iterator operator+(const difference_type& off) const { return const_iterator(array_iterator::_pos + off); }
        const_iterator operator-(const difference_type& off) const { return const_iterator(array_iterator::_pos - off); }

        const_iterator& operator+=(const difference_type& off) { array_iterator::_pos += off; return *this; }
        const_iterator& operator-=(const difference_type& off) { array_iterator::_pos -= off; return *this; }

        difference_type operator-(const const_iterator& rhs) const { return array_iterator::_pos - rhs._pos; }

        const_reference operator*()  const { return *array_iterator::_pos; }
        const_pointer   operator->() const { return  array_iterator::_pos; }
    };

    class iterator : public const_iterator
    {
    public:
        using const_iterator::const_iterator;

        //INCREMENT/DECREMENT OPERATORS
        iterator& operator++() { ++array_iterator::_pos; return *this; }
        iterator& operator--() { --array_iterator::_pos; return *this; }
        iterator  operator++(int) { iterator temp(*this); operator++(); return temp; }
        iterator  operator--(int) { iterator temp(*this); operator--(); return temp; }

        //ARITHMETIC OPERATORS
        iterator operator+(const difference_type& off) const { return iterator(array_iterator::_pos + off); }
        iterator operator-(const difference_type& off) const { return iterator(array_iterator::_pos - off); }

        iterator& operator+=(const difference_type& off) { array_iterator::_pos += off; return *this; }
        iterator& operator-=(const difference_type& off) { array_iterator::_pos -= off; return *this; }

        difference_type operator-(const iterator& rhs) const { return array_iterator::_pos - rhs._pos; }

        reference operator*()  const { return *array_iterator::_pos; }
        pointer   operator->() const { return  array_iterator::_pos; }
    };

    class const_reverse_iterator : public array_iterator
    {
    public:
        using array_iterator::array_iterator;

        //INCREMENT/DECREMENT OPERATORS
        const_reverse_iterator& operator++() { --array_iterator::_pos; return *this; }
        const_reverse_iterator& operator--() { ++array_iterator::_pos; return *this; }
        const_reverse_iterator  operator++(int) { const_reverse_iterator temp(*this); operator++(); return temp; }
        const_reverse_iterator  operator--(int) { const_reverse_iterator temp(*this); operator--(); return temp; }

        //ARITHMETIC OPERATORS
        const_reverse_iterator operator+(const difference_type& off) const { return const_reverse_iterator(array_iterator::_pos - off); }
        const_reverse_iterator operator-(const difference_type& off) const { return const_reverse_iterator(array_iterator::_pos + off); }

        const_reverse_iterator& operator+=(const difference_type& off) { array_iterator::_pos -= off; return *this; }
        const_reverse_iterator& operator-=(const difference_type& off) { array_iterator::_pos += off; return *this; }

        difference_type operator-(const const_reverse_iterator& rhs) const { return -(array_iterator::_pos - rhs._pos); }

        const_reference operator*()  const { return *array_iterator::_pos; }
        const_pointer   operator->() const { return  array_iterator::_pos; }

        const_iterator base() const { return const_iterator(array_iterator::_pos); }
    };

    class reverse_iterator : public const_reverse_iterator
    {
    public:
        using const_reverse_iterator::const_reverse_iterator;

        //INCREMENT/DECREMENT OPERATORS
        reverse_iterator& operator++() { --array_iterator::_pos; return *this; }
        reverse_iterator& operator--() { ++array_iterator::_pos; return *this; }
        reverse_iterator  operator++(int) { reverse_iterator temp(*this); operator++(); return temp; }
        reverse_iterator  operator--(int) { reverse_iterator temp(*this); operator--(); return temp; }

        //ARITHMETIC OPERATORS
        reverse_iterator operator+(const difference_type& off) const { return reverse_iterator(array_iterator::_pos - off); }
        reverse_iterator operator-(const difference_type& off) const { return reverse_iterator(array_iterator::_pos + off); }

        reverse_iterator& operator+=(const difference_type& off) { array_iterator::_pos -= off; return *this; }
        reverse_iterator& operator-=(const difference_type& off) { array_iterator::_pos += off; return *this; }

        difference_type operator-(const reverse_iterator& rhs) const { return -(array_iterator::_pos - rhs._pos); }

        reference operator*()  const { return *array_iterator::_pos; }
        pointer   operator->() const { return  array_iterator::_pos; }

        iterator base() const { return iterator(array_iterator::_pos); }  //BUG HERE!!!
    };

public: //public to allow aggregate initialization and no need for constructors!!
    value_type _data[Size == 0 ? 1 : Size];

public:
    //ACCESS FUNCTIONS
    reference front() { return _data[0]; }
    reference back()  { return _data[Size - 1]; }

    const_reference front() const { return _data[0]; }
    const_reference back()  const { return _data[Size - 1]; }

    reference operator[](const size_type& index)       
    {   //bounds checking regardless of C++ standard
        if (index < 0 || index >= Size)
            throw std::out_of_range("Index out of bounds!");

        return _data[index]; 
    }

    const_reference operator[](const size_type& index) const 
    {
        if (index < 0 || index >= Size)
            throw std::out_of_range("Index out of bounds!");

        return _data[index]; 
    }

    reference       at(const size_type& index)       { return operator[](index); }
    const_reference at(const size_type& index) const { return operator[](index); }

    template<std::size_t Index> //get<> to be preferred over [] or .at() because it offers
    reference get()                 //compile-time bounds checking
    {
        static_assert(Index >= 0 && Index < Size, "blew::array::get<>() Invalid index!");
        return _data[Index];
    }

    template<std::size_t Index>
    const_reference get() const
    {
        static_assert(Index >= 0 && Index < Size, "blew::array::get<>() Invalid index!");
        return _data[Index];
    }

    pointer data()             noexcept { return _data; }
    const_pointer data() const noexcept { return _data; }

    //CAPACITY FUNCTIONS
    constexpr size_type size()     const noexcept { return Size; }
    constexpr size_type max_size() const noexcept { return Size; }
    constexpr bool      empty()    const noexcept { return !Size; }

    //ITERATORS
    iterator begin() noexcept { return iterator(_data); }
    iterator end()   noexcept { return iterator(_data + Size); }

    const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return const_iterator(const_cast<pointer>(_data)); }
    const_iterator end()   const noexcept { return const_iterator(const_cast<pointer>(_data + Size)); }

    const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return const_iterator(const_cast<pointer>(_data)); }
    const_iterator cend()   const noexcept { return const_iterator(const_cast<pointer>(_data + Size)); }

    //REVERSE ITERATORS
    reverse_iterator rbegin() noexcept { return reverse_iterator(_data + Size - 1); }
    reverse_iterator rend()   noexcept { return reverse_iterator(_data - 1); }

    const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept { return const_reverse_iterator(const_cast<pointer>(_data + Size - 1)); }
    const_reverse_iterator rend()   const noexcept { return const_reverse_iterator(const_cast<pointer>(_data - 1)); }

    const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const noexcept { return const_reverse_iterator(const_cast<pointer>(_data + Size - 1)); }
    const_reverse_iterator crend()   const noexcept { return const_reverse_iterator(const_cast<pointer>(_data - 1)); }

    //OTHER FUNCTIONS AND ALGORITHMS
    void swap(array& rhs) noexcept 
    {   //std::swap calls std::swap_ranges
        std::swap(*this, rhs); 
    }

    //fill
    void fill(const value_type& val)
    {
        for (size_type i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
            _data[i] = val;
    }

    //assign
    void assign(const value_type& val)
    {
        for (size_type i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
            _data[i] = val;
    }

    template<class InputIt,
    class = std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_convertible<value_type, typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>::value
    >>
    void assign(InputIt first, InputIt last)
    {
        size_type i = 0;
        for (; first != last; ++first)
            _data[i++] = *first;
    }

    //replace
    void replace(const value_type& val, const value_type& other_val)
    {
        for (size_type i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        {
            if (_data[i] == val)
                _data[i] = other_val;
        }
    }

    template<class Predicate>
    void replace_if(Predicate predicate, const value_type& other_val)
    {
        for (size_type i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        {
            if (predicate(_data[i]))
                _data[i] = other_val;
        }
    }

    template<class Predicate>
    void replace_if_not(Predicate predicate, const value_type& other_val)
    {
        for (size_type i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        {
            if (!predicate(_data[i]))
                _data[i] = other_val;
        }
    }

    //count
    size_type count(const value_type& val)
    {
        size_type counter = 0;
        for (size_type i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        {
            if (_data[i] == val)
                ++counter;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    template<class Predicate>
    size_type count_if(Predicate predicate)
    {
        size_type counter = 0;
        for (size_type i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        {
            if (predicate(_data[i]))
                ++counter;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    template<class Predicate>
    size_type count_if_not(Predicate predicate)
    {
        size_type counter = 0;
        for (size_type i = 0; i < Size; ++i)
        {
            if (!predicate(_data[i]))
                ++counter;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    template<class Predicate = std::less<>>
    void sort(Predicate predicate)
    {
        std::sort(_data, _data + Size, predicate);
    }

    //FRIEND FUNCTIONS
    //RELATIONAL OPERATORS ON blew::array<T, N>
    friend bool operator==(const array& lhs, const array& rhs)
    {
        return std::equal(lhs.cbegin(), lhs.cend(), rhs.cbegin(), rhs.cend());
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const array& lhs, const array& rhs)
    {
        return !std::equal(lhs.cbegin(), lhs.cend(), rhs.cbegin(), rhs.cend());
    }

    friend bool operator<(const array& lhs, const array& rhs)
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.cbegin(), lhs.cend(), rhs.cbegin(), rhs.cend());
    }

    friend bool operator>(const array& lhs, const array& rhs)
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(lhs.cbegin(), lhs.cend(),
                                            rhs.cbegin(), rhs.cend(), std::greater<>());
    }

    friend bool operator<=(const array& lhs, const array& rhs)
    {
        return operator==(lhs, rhs) || operator<(lhs, rhs);
    }

    friend bool operator>=(const array& lhs, const array& rhs)
    {
        return operator==(lhs, rhs) || operator>(lhs, rhs);
    }
};  


//NON-MEMBER FUNCTIONS
template<std::size_t Index, class ArrType, std::size_t Size> constexpr
ArrType& get(array<ArrType, Size>& arr) noexcept
{
    return arr.get<Index>();
}

template<std::size_t Index, class ArrType, std::size_t Size> constexpr
const ArrType& get(const array<ArrType, Size>& arr) noexcept
{
    return arr.get<Index>();
}
```

Comment: You really don't have to make `iterator` and `const_iterator` two distinct classes! Use a template class instead, check this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/74647/39810

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bugs:

1. Your iterators default-constructor is bad: You need to set the member-pointer to `nullptr`!
2. Your iterators are missing the index-operator.

Iterators:

3. You should read about SCARY iterators. The standard-library uses them for versatility and avoidance of duplicate code:
   [What are SCARY iterators?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14391705)

   In a nutshell, your iterators should only be dependent on the type-argument, not on the length-argument.
4. There is no reason to write your own reverse-iterators.
   Just use [`std::reverse_iterator`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator).
5. There's also no reason to have a separate const_iterator-template once you use SCARY iterators: Just use a normal iterator with a constant value-type.

   If you want to enable assignment from non-constant to constant iterators, add a free-function user-defined conversion.

---

6. Your template-arguments have curious names. `T` and `N` would be customary.
7. "*bounds checking regardless of C++ standard*": Thanks for not making it `noexcept`, and thus breaking everyones expectations.
   Also, what do you expect the calling code to do when it gets an *impossible* exception?
   Just `std::terminate()` directly on detecting such internal corruption.
8. `at` now should have bounds-checking and throw on out-of-bound-access. As it's more complicated than a simple field-access, you should implement the non-const version in terms of the const version, using a const_cast. Not the other way around, that would violate the standard, strictly speaking.
9. `front` and `back` should just call `std::terminate` if `N == 0`, as calling them is a bug.
10. I suggest you prefer SFINAE on the return-type instead of using an additional template-argument. That way, it isn't part of the symbol-name.
11. You are missing many opportunities for marking things `noexcept` and/or `constexpr`.
12. I wouldn't add so many algorithms as member-functions, as the free function algorithms in the standard library are perfectly adequate.
13. If a type is cheap to copy, prefer passing it by value.

Comment: I could not find much `good` information about SCARY iterators. But as far as I could understand, I just have a single iterator class and then: `using iterator = scary_iterator<T>;` and `using const_iterator = scary_iterator<const T>;`. I managed to get that far. But then how would I make `const_iterator` constructible from `iterator`?

Comment: Well, first of all, that isn't in the iterator-requirements, so not strictly neccessary. Aside from that, just add a user-defined conversion: `template<class T> constexpr operator iterator<const T>(iterator<T> x) noexcept { return iterator<const T>(x.operator->()); }`